# Finding text contained in an element

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a span element with a keyword in it that I'd like to find.  How can I best do this with watir?

I can't figure out how to find the span with my text in it.  I can find the spans, but narrowing down to the one with my keyword in it isn't working-- not sure how to stick a regex into this statement below.

Here's what I've got so far, to give an idea on what I'm after:

```
@browser.div(:id, 'my_div_element').span(:text, 'my keyword here').exists?
```

..that returns 'false' at the moment.  I can find the spans but when I try narrowing down with the `:text` bit I run into a wall.  And I know my keyword is in there.

Comment: To locate the span based on a regex, you should be able to do this: `@b.div(:id, 'div_element').span(:text, /keyword/).exists?`  Can you post sample HTML as well?

Comment: darn it, I had tried slashes with the single quotes, which is not what I should have done.  Your example fixed it for me.  If you post an answer I'll be happy to mark it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example provided, this is the syntax for locating text (enclosed in <div> and <span> tags) using regex:

`@b.div(:id, 'div_element').span(:text, /keyword/).exists?`